# Onclick save canvas as image on server

Tags: html, image, canvas, onclick, save

I have this canvas. I have written some javascript that allows the user to draw on the canvas in different colors and pen sizes.

```
<style>
#myCanvas{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
border:1px solid black;
z-index:0;
}
</style>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="600"></canvas>
```

How would I have the user click on a button or an input with **type="button"** and have the image save to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your canvas artwork as an encoded image with `canvas.toDataURL`

Then you can use AJAX to submit that encoded image data to your server.

Here's some code using jQuery+AJAX to POST the image data to a file on your server.

**Client Side in your button-click event:**

```
// create a dataUrl from the canvas

var dataURL= canvas.toDataURL();

// post the dataUrl to php

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "upload.php",
  data: {image: dataURL}
}).done(function( respond ) {
  // you will get back the temp file name
  // or "Unable to save this image."
  console.log(respond);
});
```

You didn't mention what server you're using, but PHP is a common server.

**Server File: upload.php**

```
<?php

// make sure the image-data exists and is not empty
// xampp is particularly sensitive to empty image-data 
if ( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"]) ) {    

    // get the dataURL
    $dataURL = $_POST["image"];  

    // the dataURL has a prefix (mimetype+datatype) 
    // that we don't want, so strip that prefix off
    $parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
    $data = $parts[1];  

    // Decode base64 data, resulting in an image
    $data = base64_decode($data);  

    // create a temporary unique file name
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

    // write the file to the upload directory
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    // return the temp file name (success)
    // or return an error message just to frustrate the user (kidding!)
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save this image.';

}
```

**Some usual gotchas:**

- Make sure you have properly set up your upload directory.
- Make sure you have permissions set properly on the upload directory.